# geom_density_ridges length of y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

my code is quite similar to the following example.  I have categories (internally stored as factors) and I need to plot multiple graphs.
When I plot them the tich for the y-axis are not in the exact same height as you can see in the figure.  Is there a solution for this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library('grid')
a=ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()
b=ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()


test=cbind(ggplotGrob(a), ggplotGrob(b),size="last")
grid.draw(test)
```

[image].imgur.com/gTshi.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to [reshape the data from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) first, in this case with package `reshape2`, then use `ggplot2`'s faceting.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

long_iris <- reshape2::melt(iris[c(1, 2, 5)], id.vars = "Species")

g <- ggplot(long_iris) + 
  geom_density_ridges(aes(x = value, y = Species)) +
  theme_ridges() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)

g
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an ..ndensity.. option for `height` argument

`library(devtools)`

`install_github("clauswilke/ggridges")`

`a <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, height = ..ndensity..)) + geom_density_ridges()`

`b <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Species, height = ..ndensity..)) + geom_density_ridges()`

`test <- cbind(ggplotGrob(a), ggplotGrob(b),size="last")`

`grid.draw(test)`

Comment: Why do you say *it doesn't work with the CRAN package version*? My `ggridges` package version is 0.5.1, the same as CRAN's and your code did work. Upvote, BTW.

Comment: idk, probably something was wrong with my CRAN package installation, i'll check.

Comment: yep, i've reinstalled the package from CRAN and it works just fine, so I've edited the initial comment in order not to confuse anyone.

Comment: It's a very good solution and I would like to endorse it more (I upvoted it).  Sorry if I didn't add the "accepted answer".   It works also with separate plots (one plot for each different file) without the need to put them in a grid.